# Shared DataStore

Tags: share, datastore

I am running an education environment and running out of disk space.  Is it possible to use only one Virtual Disk (using HP EVA) as a data store for 6 individual Lab systems.  We have a SAN installed and we are using HP BL460 G7 blades.

I would be running W2K8 R2.  These are just to set up the VM clients to demonstrate using ESXi.  No production is intended, nothing will actually run on these VM's. We are trying to demonstrate how VM's can be created along with basics of VMotion to migrate servers. I will be creating a DataStore for each of 6 systems. Then I will be installing W2K8.  As far as I can tell it is doable.  I was just wondering if there was a limit to how many ESX servers could share 1 datastore.

Thanks for the answer you provided me with TomTom!

Comment: Maybe the education environment should educate you to give a LITTLE more relevant information? Generally - yes, it is possible. Details depend on what your lab systems run as software, which you dont say. Hecy, how do I make puizza? I have a fridge to store the ingredients.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure this is the clearest question I've ever read but if I have read it right then I think you want to know that there is a 32 host per LUN/datastore limit - and I routinely do go to this limit with 32-host clusters so it works just fine. Does that answer your question?